# error "read only file system" when I'm trying to create file using bash script in AWS Lambda function (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I have python (3.8) Lambda function that connected to EFS, in mount `/mnt/my-mount`.

I want to run a bash script via the function, so I created another file `script.sh`.

This is the python function:

```
import json
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    os.system("sh script.sh")
```

and bash script `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch hello.txt
```

and I get the following error:

`cannot touch script.sh: Read-only file system`

Notes:

- I can create file using the python function (f.write).
- If I run `os.system("chmod 777 a.sh")`, again I get `Read-Only file system`.
- If I use `rc = subprocess.call("bash a.sh")`, I get `No such file or directory: 'bash a.sh'`
- The EFS has access point for user `1000:1000` with `777` permissions.

Comment: Do you need to specify an absolute path such as `touch /mnt/my-mount/hello.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be due to having the Lambda role without proper write permissions. You should attach the proper policy or define your custom one:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Along with the permission, the issue will be with ***directory path*** of Access Point. If you are mounting it in lambda, the root directory path **"/"** will give permission denied issue. So, make sure you use some other absolute path other than default **"/"**.

**Access Point Configuration**
[image: access point configuration]

**Lambda Configuration**
[image: lambda configuration]